# C# 9.0 Source generator - ignoring classes compilation with certain attribute

Tags: c#, roslyn, csharp-source-generator

#### The Issue:

I have a source generator class which generates a code contains `async`/`await` keywords,
The generator also compiles this class:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <TestMethod>d__0 : IAsyncStateMachine
{
    ...
}
```

Is there any way to ignore those classes containing `[CompilerGenerated]` attribute?

## Update:

#### This question is a followup to this one:

#### The Issue:

Trying to implement an auto dependency injection registrator, my conventions are very strict so it will be very useful.

I'm having issues with registering classes containing async methods, the container seems to adress to these methods while registering the class.

#### About the project:

- The Soruce generator is netstandard2.0
- The Models and the Executable are net5.0
- When the method is not asynchronous everything works perfectly
- The MetadataReference are not actually needed I just want to avoid answers addressing to those

#### TL;DL

Some of the reproduction errors:

- CS0103    The name 'd__0' does not exist in the current context
- CS0103    The name 'TestMethod' does not exist in the current context
- CS1525    Invalid expression term '<'
- CS1002    ; expected

#### The code:

### Source Generator Project:

```cs
namespace Test.Build.Tools
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
    using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text;

    /// <summary>
    /// Auto register source generator.
    /// </summary>
    [Generator]
    public class AutoRegisterSourceGenerator : ISourceGenerator
    {
        /// <inheritdoc/>
        public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
        {
        }

        /// <inheritdoc/>
        public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new("namespace Test.Extensions.DependencyInjection\n"
                                            + "{\n"
                                            + "    using System;\n"
                                            + "    using System.Threading.Tasks;\n"
                                            + "    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;\n");
            List<string> namespaces = new();

            string defaultPath = typeof(object).Assembly.Location.Replace("mscorlib", "{0}");

            List<MetadataReference> references = new()
            {
                { MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(string.Format(defaultPath, "System.Threading.Tasks")) }
            };

            var types = GetAllTypes(context.Compilation);
            var neededTypes = types.Where(t =>
            {
                string @namespace = t.ContainingNamespace.ToString();

                if (@namespace.Contains("Test")
                && !t.Interfaces.IsEmpty
                && t.TypeKind == TypeKind.Class)
                {
                    namespaces.Add(t.ContainingNamespace.ToString());
                    namespaces.Add(t.Interfaces[0].ContainingNamespace.ToString());
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }).ToList();

            namespaces.Distinct().OrderBy(n => n.ToString()).ToList().ForEach(n => stringBuilder.Append($"    using {n};\n"));

            stringBuilder.Append(
                "    /// <summary>\n" +
                "    /// Service registrator class.\n" +
                "    /// </summary>\n" +
                "    public static class ServicesRegistrator\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "        /// <summary>\n" +
                "        /// Register dependency injection instances.\n" +
                "        /// </summary>\n" +
                "        /// <param name=\"services\">Startup services.</param>\n" +
                "        /// <returns>The given <see cref=\"IServiceCollection\"/> instance.</returns>\n" +
                "        public static IServiceCollection RegisterDomainModel(this IServiceCollection services)\n" +
                "        {\n");

            foreach (var type in neededTypes)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append($"            services.AddScoped<I{type.Name}, {type.Name}>();");
                stringBuilder.AppendLine();
            }

            stringBuilder.Append("            return services;\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "}\n");

            context.Compilation.AddReferences(references);

            context.AddSource("ServicesRegistrator", SourceText.From(stringBuilder.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8));
        }

        IEnumerable<INamedTypeSymbol> GetAllTypes(Compilation compilation) =>
            GetAllTypes(compilation.GlobalNamespace);

        IEnumerable<INamedTypeSymbol> GetAllTypes(INamespaceSymbol @namespace)
        {
            foreach (var type in @namespace.GetTypeMembers())
                foreach (var nestedType in GetNestedTypes(type))
                    yield return nestedType;

            foreach (var nestedNamespace in @namespace.GetNamespaceMembers())
                foreach (var type in GetAllTypes(nestedNamespace))
                    yield return type;
        }

        IEnumerable<INamedTypeSymbol> GetNestedTypes(INamedTypeSymbol type)
        {
            yield return type;
            foreach (var nestedType in type.GetTypeMembers()
                .SelectMany(nestedType => GetNestedTypes(nestedType)))
                yield return nestedType;
        }
    }
}
```

### Models Project:

```cs
namespace TestClasses
{
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public interface ITestClass
    {
        public Task TestMethod();
    }
}

namespace TestClasses.Model
{
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public class TestClass : ITestClass
    {
        public async Task TestMethod()
        {
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Executable

```cs
using Executable;

Program.Rgister();

namespace Executable
{
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Test.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using TestClasses;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Rgister()
        {
            IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.RegisterDomainModel();

            var x = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<ITestClass>();

            x.TestMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

## Update:

#### The Generated Code:

```cs
namespace Test.Extensions.DependencyInjection
{
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using TestClasses;
    using TestClasses.Model;
    /// <summary>
    /// Service registrator class.
    /// </summary>

    public static class ServicesRegistrator
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Register dependency injection instances.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="services">Startup services.</param>
        /// <returns>The given <see cref="IServiceCollection"/> instance.</returns>
        public static IServiceCollection RegisterDomainModel(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<ITestClass, TestClass>();
            return services;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? What do you want to achieve? Ignore how? Excluding them from linking would mean that your program cannot run.

Comment: In the linked question I've posted that because of those classes my program won't complie.

Comment: A question should be self contained. In the context of this question, there is no reason to exclude those classes

Comment: Got it and edited :)